# How to open powerpoint file in a browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, powerpoint

I'm trying to embed a powerpoint presentation in my offline site but fail to find a suitable open source library that can view my pptx file. I want to use a viewer that can view the pptx content and retain the transition etc. of the pptx file. Then detect if the user reach the end of the slide. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Would https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ be the right place to ask this?

Comment: ok sir im going to ask it there. Thank you for pointing it out